# Perform MessageActions on Messages for .Net 6 Isolated Worker ServiceBusTriggers

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, .net-6.0

I want to be able to perform flexible actions on Service Bus Messages through a **.Net 6 out-of-process** `ServiceBusTrigger`. Actions include abandoning, completing, deferring, as well as dead-letter-queuing messages. I.e. the same actions that are available through the `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` and `ServiceBusMessageActions` bindings of the **in-process** `ServiceBusTrigger`.

However, out-of-process triggers seem only to be able to bind the message body as a `string`, as well as the `FunctionContext`. Are the described actions available for out-of-process triggers in some other way? If not, do you know if it's on the roadmap for near future releases?

Example of how the actions are available for in-process triggers:

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(InProcessReceiver))]
public async Task RunAsync(
   [ServiceBusTrigger("%TOPIC_NAME%", "%SUB_NAME%", Connection="CONNECTION_NAME")] 
   ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
   ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions
)
{
   await messageActions.DeadLetterMessageAsync(message);
   //await messageActions.AbandonMessageAsync(message);
   //await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
   //await messageActions.DeferMessageAsync(message);
}
```

Example of out-of-process trigger, for which I want to do the same things as above

```cs
[Function(nameof(OutOfProcessReceiver))]
public async Task RunAsync(
   [ServiceBusTrigger("%TOPIC_NAME%", "%SUB_NAME%", Connection="CONNECTION_NAME")] 
   string mySbMsg
)
{   
   //How to access message actions and bind them to the current message here?          
}
```

As mentioned by the Microsoft team in this [roadmap blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/net-on-azure-functions-roadmap/ba-p/2197916), the future is isolated. Therefore I'm trying to avoid in-process, but I realize that it might be the only solution for now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same question.  I'd like to bind to the equivalent of a BrokeredMessage/Message/ServiceBusReceivedMessage.  Strings and pocos only it seems?  Seems like binding to a base message type would be the same as your own POCO.

Comment: @pseabury We ended up migrating from out-of-process to in-process for the current project, for now. Still .Net 6 and it seems to work fine with the bindings. Luckily for us, the project was small. Hope you find a solution that works for you!

Comment: I went ahead and wrote some extensions that parse the metadata I need and the body from the received message & context.  We pass some required information around in the UserProperties.  It is not difficult, just inconvenient.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: it's July 2023, and still no fix for this issue. Not sure in .Net 8 it would be solved.

Comment: @SharifYazdian They released support for MessageActions just now, see my recent answer below for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: as of version 5.14.0, `ServiceBusMessageActions` can be injected into the functions for message settlement operations. A bug with dead-lettering was fixed in 5.14.1

Example:

```
public async Task Run(
   [ServiceBusTrigger("queue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
   ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
   ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
{
 _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
 _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);

 await messageActions.DeadLetterMessageAsync(message);
}
```

---

**Original**

> Are the described actions available for out-of-process triggers in some other way? If not, do you know if it's on the roadmap for near future releases?

At the moment it's not possible. Out of process/isolated worker SDK cannot pass to the Function native SDK types. There are a few related issues you can track for updates.

- [IMessageReceiver on ServiceBusTrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/293)
- [With a ServiceBusTrigger, how to go from string/byte[] to Message?](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/384)

Comment: What is interesting here (and I'm hope I'm not wrong), is that by simply using ServiceBusMessageActions in the method signature, will make this an in-process function execution rather than an out-of-process function.  If this is true, then I've been chasing why Startup class seems to be required for my .NET Isolated defined Azure Function!

Comment: The use of this class cannot turn one SDK into another, Richard 

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on, but in this SO post, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77730033/176338  I documented the function will not run using 5.14, but runs find (but without ServiceBusActions) in 5.13.  I'm thinking its a Linux related issue? Moving to a Windows App Service plan to see if that changes the behaviour