# ServiceBusTrigger does not contain Autocomplete property

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-7.0

I am working with .NET 7 Azure Function app and the `ServiceBusTrigger` attribute does not contain `Autocomplete` property. I also don't see a way to import `MessageReceiver` to manually complete/deadqueue the message. What are my options?

```
[Function("SendQueuedEmailsFunction")]
public async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("emails", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] string myQueueItem)
```

UPD:
[Perform MessageActions on Messages for .Net 6 Isolated Worker ServiceBusTriggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082374/perform-messageactions-on-messages-for-net-6-isolated-worker-servicebustriggers)

It seems that this is supported only by in-process functions? But .NET 7 does not support in-process? It means the only way is to downgrade to .NET 6 and switch to in process?

Comment: Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=isolated-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings, You can make use of `"extensions": {
  "serviceBus": {
    "messageHandlerOptions": {
      "autoComplete": true
    }
  }
}` in the host.json file

Answer (score 1):

- You are correct that the `ServiceBusTrigger` attribute in .NET 7 does not contain the `Autocomplete` property.
- This is because the `ServiceBusTrigger` attribute is now used for both in-process and isolated worker functions, and the `Autocomplete` property is only supported for in-process functions.
- However, there are still a few ways to manually complete  messages in .NET 7 Azure Functions with the ServiceBusTrigger attribute.

Here is an example of how to use the  `ServiceBusReceiver` class to manually complete a message:

`Function.cs`

```cs
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
    
    public class ProcessServiceBusMessageFunction
    {
        private readonly ServiceBusReceiver _serviceBusReceiver;
    
        public ProcessServiceBusMessageFunction(ServiceBusReceiver serviceBusReceiver)
        {
            _serviceBusReceiver = serviceBusReceiver;
        }
    
        [Function("ProcessServiceBusMessageFunction")]
        public async Task RunAsync(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
            FunctionContext context)
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger<ProcessServiceBusMessageFunction>();
    
            try
            {
                string messageBody = message.Body.ToString();
                logger.LogInformation($"Processing message: {messageBody}");
    

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    
                // If processing is successful, complete the message
                await _serviceBusReceiver.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
    
                logger.LogInformation($"Message processed and completed: {messageBody}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await _serviceBusReceiver.AbandonMessageAsync(message);
    
                logger.LogError(ex, "Error processing Service Bus message.");
            }
        }
    }
```

`local.settings.json`

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "ServiceBusConnection": "YourConnectionString",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

**Result**
[image]

I have refered to this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver.completemessageasync?view=azure-dotnet)