# Receive one message in one session using Azure ServiceBus but after the CompleteMessageAsync

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusSessionProcessor` and receiving one session message at a time, with the `AutoCompleteMessages = false`.

Is it possible not to receive the next message from the same session until `CompleteMessageAsync` is called on a message of that session?

Right now, after the Message Handler has finished, the next message is being received no matter if I have called the `CompleteMessageAsync` or not.

These are the options for the ServiceBusSessionProcessor:

```
var processorSessionOptions = new ServiceBusSessionProcessorOptions()
{
    AutoCompleteMessages = false,
    MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
    MaxConcurrentSessions = 5,
    MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession = 1
};
```

I've tried to receive only one message of the session and not receiving the next one not before the `CompleteMessageAsync` is called on the first one.

The result I'm getting is that when the message handler finished, the next session message is being received.

Comment: The session processor will always pick up the next session if the currently processed session has no messages and times out.  I guess I don't quite understand the **problem** you're solving. Mind elaborating?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments @Sean Feldman The session processor will always pick up the next session if the current session has no messages that need to be processed.

Yes, it is not possible to receive the next message from the same session until CompleteMessageAsync is called on a message of that session for Azure Service [Bus](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions.md).

AFAIK, The [ServiceBusSessionProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebussessionprocessoroptions?view=azure-dotnet) does not offer a way to block the next message from being received until the first one has been [completed](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample05_SessionProcessor.md). However, the MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession option may be used to limit the number of concurrent calls per session to one. This ensures that for each session, only one message is handled at a time. So it will ensure that only one [message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) is being processed at a time for each session.

The Autocomplete property is supported for up to .net 6 and not in .net 7.0 For more details refer to this  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77187316/servicebustrigger-does-not-contain-autocomplete-property/77206002#77206002).

```cs
 string connectionString = "";
    string queueName = " ";

    var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
    ServiceBusProcessor processor = client.CreateProcessor(queueName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions
    {
        MaxConcurrentCalls = 5,
        AutoCompleteMessages = false
    });

    processor.ProcessMessageAsync += ProcessMessageAsync;
    processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ProcessErrorAsync;

    await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop receiving...");
    Console.ReadKey();

    await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
    await processor.CloseAsync();
}

private static async Task ProcessMessageAsync(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
{
    var message = args.Message;

    // Your processing logic here

    // Simulate processing
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    // Complete the message
    await args.CompleteMessageAsync(message);

    Console.WriteLine($"Message processed and completed.");
}

private static Task ProcessErrorAsync(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error processing message: {args.Exception.Message}");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This does not address the question and just regurgitates Sean's statement.

Comment: @malber updated the answer