# Can ApplicationProperties/CustomProperties be set on the ServiceBusMessage when working with ServiceBusOutput-outputbinding in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, function, azure-functions, servicebus

I'm using the ServiceBusOutput in my C# function, but I need to set an ApplicationProperty on the message I'm sending, as it's used by the topic-subscription to filter the message to the relevant subscriptions. However, when I use the ServiceBusMessage-object as the return-object and set the ApplicationProperty on it, the entire ServiceBusMessage gets used as the body. This is not the desired result, as I want my original body (passed to the ServiceBusMessage) as messagebody. When I pass the body as return-object, the body of the message is correct, but there is no way for me to set the ApplicationProperties as far as I know (no way to pass them in the ServiceBusOutput-attribute).

Am I missing something, or is it just not possible to add ApplicationProperties when using the outputbinding?

```cs
var message = new ServiceBusMessage("body");
message.ApplicationProperties.Add("Type", "Type1");

return message;
```

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention I'm using the isolated worker.
I've also added a more complete snippet of my function, as I'm trying to both write something to Cosmos and post a message on ServiceBus.

```cs
public class ListenerFunction
{
    private readonly ILogger<ListenerFunction> _logger;
    public ListenerFunction(ILogger<ListenerFunction> logger)
    {
        _logger = Guard.Against.Null(logger, nameof(logger));
    }

    [Function("ListenerFunction")]
    public ListenerFunctionOutput Run([ServiceBusTrigger(
            "%Topic%",
            "%Subscription%",
            Connection = "connection",
            IsSessionsEnabled = false)] ServiceBusMessageWithBlobUrl serviceBusMessageWithBlobUrl,
        [BlobInput("{UploadedBlobUrl}", Connection = "blobConnection")] Entity entity,
        FunctionContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {inputMaterialEventServiceBusMessage}", serviceBusMessageWithBlobUrl.ToString());

        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        var output =  new ListenerFunctionOutput
        {
            CosmosDbDocument = entity with { Id = id},
            ServiceBusNotification = new ServiceBusMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new EntityNotification(id, serviceBusMessageWithBlobUrl.CorrelationId, entity with { Id = id}), Formatting.Indented))
        };
        output.ServiceBusNotification.ApplicationProperties.Add("Type", "Type1");


        return output;

        
    }

    public class ListenerFunctionOutput
    {
        [CosmosDBOutput(databaseName: "%database%", containerName: "%container%", Connection = "databaseConnection")]
        public Entity CosmosDbDocument { get; set; }

        [ServiceBusOutput("%topic%", EntityType = ServiceBusEntityType.Topic, Connection = "connection")]
        public ServiceBusMessage ServiceBusNotification { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to return a ServiceBusMessage from ServiceBusOutput but it doesn't work so reported it as an issue. The auto JSON deserialisation doesn't work either in isolated worker but that issue seems to still be open. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/3038

Comment: it seems isolated worked doesn't have the same functionality as in-process. This link has some interesting links to issues and a way to manually deal with messages without ServiceBusOutput. I use these methods instead as isolated worker is too restrictive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082374/perform-messageactions-on-messages-for-net-6-isolated-worker-servicebustriggers

Comment: @Seppe Goossens Provided the answer below

Comment: Thanks @codebrane , that was my solution as well, using the ServiceBusSender. But this is a lot more elaborate than just adding the outputbinding and be done with it. :)
I am indeed using the isolated worker, so that might be the reason it's not working as I'd expect, something I didn't include in my question as I didn't think of it as the possible culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`Function.cs:`**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp82
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "connec")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log, [ServiceBus("rithwikqueue", Connection = "connec")] out Message message)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
            message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myQueueItem));
            message.UserProperties.Add("sender", "Chotu");


        }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I edited the question with more info about my function. Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no *current* way of doing this in Isolated with the ServiceBusOutputAttribute.

Instead, send the message via code. I hit this exact same issue, and I've stripped out the output attribute and am using MassTransit instead. Works perfectly for my use case.