# Azure Isolated Function / ServiceBus Topic Binding / Will NOT deploy

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics, .net-8.0

I have been fighting with this, making small steps forward and backward, and I'm exasperated.

I'm getting this error message in my Logs after a deploy (but works fine locally)

```
    Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExternalStartupException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.GrpcServicesExtensions.AddGrpc (Grpc.AspNetCore.Server, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d754f35622e28bad)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Rpc.WebJobsExtensionBuilderRpcExtensions.AddCoreServices (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Rpc, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Rpc\WebJobsExtensionBuilderRpcExtensions.cs:39)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Rpc.WebJobsExtensionBuilderRpcExtensions.MapWorkerGrpcService (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Rpc, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Rpc\WebJobsExtensionBuilderRpcExtensions.cs:31)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.ServiceBusHostBuilderExtensions.AddServiceBus (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus, Version=5.13.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.ServiceBusHostBuilderExtensions.AddServiceBus (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus, Version=5.13.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.ServiceBusWebJobsStartup.Configure (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus, Version=5.13.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.ConfigureStartup (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs:166)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.ConfigureAndLogUserConfiguredServices (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs:130)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.UseWebJobsStartup (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs:115)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.UseExternalStartup (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs:213)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHostBuilderExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<AddScriptHostCore>b__1 (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.28.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.cs:226)

Inner exception details:
   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My first problem is the ExternalStartupException. This is an isolated .net Azure Function, and a Startup attribute is not required.

The second problem is why  is Version 7.0.0.0 coming into play for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing? I realize this is a Console application running, but I have no reference (including any package I can tell) or project which uses this version.

Packages are as follows:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.15.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
        
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.19.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.17.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.17.1" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Sql" Version="3.0.461" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="8.0.0" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations" Version="8.0.0" />
```

Host is a Linux  AppServicePlan (P1v3: 1)

I can also see it in the Azure Function Overview with a critical error notification:
[image]

Been all over this for a few days, so i'm sure I'm into several errors that are compounding the complexity.

Comment: Richard, share a repro. You're doing something that's off.

Comment: @codeputer please share your function code and local.settings.json

Comment: I have created a barebones function using Service Bus Trigger - when I upgraded from
PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.12.0" to 5.15.0 the error of AspNetCore.Server started to appear.  I then downgraded, and the function started working.

Comment: UPDATE: So I seem to have isolated this to the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus in which the class ServiceBusMessageActions was introduced (first in 5.14).  When I use this nuget package, the deployment to Linux will not work due to GRPC and ASP.NET dependencies???

Comment: Update: I redeployed the same code base to a Windows App Service Plan, and the function is working as expected.  It appears this is a Linux issue.  Created a issue with the team at: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/230